# Facebook application doesn't popup for extended permissions on production site

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-authentication

I have done an addon for vbulletin to import facebook albums/photos to forums. Everything  is working fine on `localhost` and so on production site when I first tested it yesterday.

Now when a user is connecting with facebook account, he is not asked for extended permissions (`user_photos`) and so the addon simply not working. I cant find a reason for that. If you have a suggestion, tip or a point where I can start would be great.

```
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
   'scope' => 'user_photos'
));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user_photos` is not an "extended" permission. Its a normal read permission asked alongwith the basic permissions. It must be visible in the first permission popup. Is it?